# Recognize a user by voice android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio-fingerprinting

Friends,

I am trying to create an app that will recognize someones voice.

Here is a possible scenario:

1) The user (John) starts the app for the first time, the app asks John to create a vocal password (e.g. "Lock"). 
2) John starts the app for the second time says "Lock" --->Success!
3) Mary starts the app on Johns phone and says "Lock" --> Access is denied!

Basically recognize the user by his/her voice.

Any suggestions on how I go about this? I am new to Android. Are there any publick api's that already do this and thatr I could use.

I know that the SpeechRecognizer class in Android can recognize speech but it cannot determine who is talking. What I need is the audio fingerprint and that is something that SpeechRecognizer cannot do (for all I know).

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://echoprint.me/ to be very helpfull